# What are the most important things to include in your thesis defense presentation?

Tags: thesis, defense

If you are creating a simulator of the existing system then should you present the details about the system or your simulator? or both? How technical you should go in your defense presentation?  I have so much stuff in my report that I don't know what to put in my defense and what to leave out. I wanted to show my slides to my supervisor but he is very busy this week and I doubt he will have time for me.

I am doing a post-Masters degree known as a Doctorate of Engineering or professional doctorate and I will have 45 minutes for the presentation and 15 minutes for question. Then I will have one more hour for my defense.

Comment: Which kind of thesis? Bachelor's, Master's or PhD? How much time do you have? 15 min, 20 min, 30 min or more?

Comment: Its a post Masters degree and I have 45 minutes to defend and 15 minutes for questions.

Comment: Are you assessed, at least in part, on the presentation, or is it just a formality that you have to do before the defense? I'm assuming the latter, but just to be clear

Comment: I think I will be assessed on the presentation. I am not clear at this point what is the difference between the defense and the presentation.

Comment: Maybe the audience are different, or the people able to ask questions is different. If you're only a couple of weeks away from your defense you ought to find out quickly what the whole process will entail! This will obviously factor into the preparations you have to make (such as writing a talk)

Comment: Well in the defense part only my supervisors are available and the presentation is public.

Comment: @statboy I feel like this question may be difficult to answer comprehensively without knowing what purpose the presentation serves. For example, a presentation that wasn't being assessed would may well provide you with more freedom to pick and choose what you wanted to present. A formally assessed presentation may be more constrained. Right now, I feel you probably ought to be more concerned with understanding the process you're about to engage in than writing the presentation.

Comment: @Ian_Fin I found a document stating that I will have 45 minutes for the public presentation and 45 minutes for "restricted defense" and then they will determine my grade in 15 minutes.

Comment: @statboy Determine your grade based on what though? The public presentation or the restricted defense? If it's not clear then ask your supervisor. If your supervisor is too busy to respond then ask someone else in the institution familiar with the process (e.g. someone else acting as a supervisor). I suspect that the public presentation is relatively informal, and you can focus on whatever aspect of the thesis you like, but I'd want to know for certain if I was you.

Comment: Include your name, spelled correctly.

Comment: *Go to another student's presentation.  Now!*

Answer (score 2):

Tailor the presentation to those who assess it. You say that will be your supervisors. If that means they are people closely familiar with your subject matter, you can devote more time to project details. That means 60-70% of your time. If they are non-experts (researchers from a different department/specialization), spend less time on technical details. When in doubt, always focus more on

-What's the big question/motivation for this study

-how does your contribution tie into big question

-Why was it a difficult project to tackle (important for non-experts)

-how did you overcome those difficulties

-how can the big question be addressed now that you made your contribution?

The last ties back into the beginning and may feel repetitive to you. But it is important for people listening to the talk.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is one to ask to your principal supervisor and your adjunct/secondary supervisor if you have one.

That's also what they are there for, regardless how much time they have. They get paid also for supervisory duties. Supervision is not an extra duty that comes on top of what is in their job description, unless your local setting is unusual.

Indeed attending other thesis defenses shall give you a good first-hand flavour of what you may expect.

Good luck!